# transform a dataframe to and make it similar to an R frequency table

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has frequency counts. I created this data frame using dplyr's group by

```
a   beta    2
a   gamma   2
b   alpha   3
b   beta    5
b   gamma   9
c   beta    3
c   gamma   10
d   beta    8
```

I am trying to create a frequency table that aggregates the counts that look like a frequency table using R's table function

```
        a   b   c   d
alpha   0   3   0   0
beta    2   5   3   8
gamma   2   9   10  4
```

Comment: Is `?xtabs` what you want?

Comment: You could make a zero-matrix with the correct row and column names and then do `mat[ cbind( df[ ,2], df[,1] ] <- df[,3]`. Admittedly `xtabs` is much slicker. My suggestion generalizes to higher dimensions, though.

Comment: the counts you see there are aggregates of frequency counts from the original data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'),
                 v2 = c('beta', 'gamma', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'beta', 'gamma', 'beta'),
                 v3 = c(2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 3, 10, 8))
xtabs(v3 ~ v2 + v1, data = df)
```